# Use different regex for each iteration in a loop in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of units I want to search in a pandas dataframe and then convert those units into correctly named units and also multiply their values with a constant factor in list below. Here is the example dataframe

```
>> df
product                     info
product___A     3.5 m mini-jack
product___B     3.5 kg mini-jack
product___C     3.5mm mini-jack
product___D     3.5 millimeter mini-jack
product___E     43 centimeter mini-jack
```

Here is my implementation of the code

```
import re
import pandas as pd
units_origianal = ['Kilogram', 'millimeter', 'pounds', 'ounce', 'centimeter', 'kilometers']
units = ['kg', 'mm', 'lbs' 'oz', 'cm', 'm']
factor = [0.543, 654.53, 53.64,0.744, 43.8, 98.123]
def norm_units(x):
    for i in range(len(units)):
        if ('\d+\s'+units_origianal[i] in x or re.search('\d+'+units_origianal[i],str(x))):
            quantity = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", str(x))[0]
            resulting_quantity = float(quantity) * factor[i]
                return x.replace(quantity, resulting_quantity).replace(units_origianal[i], units[i])

df = df.apply(norm_units)


>> df
    # Expected resulting Dataframe
product                     info
product___A      344.05 m mini-jack
product___B      1.9005 kg mini-jack
product___C      2290.155 mm mini-jack
product___D      2290.155 mm mini-jack
product___E      1883.4 cm mini-jack
```

The resulting dataframe i got after running the code

```
  product info
0  None  None
1  None  None
2  None  None
3  None  None
4  None  None
```

Appreciations and thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `str.replace` with regular expression groups

```
>> factors = {'Kilogram': 0.543, 'kg': 0.543, 
              'millimeter': 654.54, 'mm': 654.54,
              'pounds': 53.64, 'lbs': 53.64,
              'ounce': 0.744, 'oz': 0.744,
              'centimeter': 43.8, 'cm': 43.8, 
              'kilometers': 98.123, 'm': 98.123}
>> pat = "(?P<val>\d+\.?\d?)\s*(?P<unit>(%s))" % '|'.join(factors)
>> def repl(p):
>>     val, unit = float(p.group('val')), p.group('unit')
>>     return str(factors[unit] * val) + ' ' + unit
>> df['info'] = df['info'].str.replace(pat, repl)
>> df

    product      info
0   product___A  343.4305 m mini-jack
1   product___B  1.9005 kg mini-jack
2   product___C  2290.89 mm mini-jack
3   product___D  2290.89 millimeter mini-jack
4   product___E  1883.3999999999999 centimeter mini-jack
```

Comment: Can I apply this to whole dataframe ? I think it will work with only one column. Actually I have messy dataset so I don't know which columns might contain the structure like info column. Also I don't know why the same code is not working for me

Comment: @muazfaiz In order to help you with this, please provide in the question an example with input and desired output that you are stuck with. Since with those that you've already provided it works pretty well.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? Callable support for `repl` parameter was added in version 0.20.0. The version I use is 0.20.1

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But what should be done in order to apply this method to whole dataframe ?